# How do I create a custom web part from a custom list in sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, sharepoint-2007

I want to create a custom web part in SharePoint 2007 that allows me to take items from an existing custom list (i.e. Title, Hyperlink, Description and photo) and then render it in a format of my choice. How can I do this using C# asp.net and a web part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sharepoint object model to achieve the same [SPList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist%28v=office.12%29.aspx) class will provide you all informations you need refer the attached link. You can use also use [DVWP](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/05/12/data-view-web-part-the-basics-insert-a-dvwp-on-your-page/) for the same